# How to rotate letters in a list of strings while preserving the strings' shapes?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I am trying to write a function `join :: [[a]] -> [[a]]` that joins the last character of a list within a list with the first character of a list within a list.

```
join ["m"] = ["m"]
join ["a","b","c"] = ["b","c","a"]
join ["goodday", "world", "i", "love", "haskell"] = ["ooddayw","orldi","l","oveh","askellg"]
join ["the", "catcher", "in", "the", "rye"] = ["hec","atcheri","nt","her","yet"]
```

I am trying to write a code that does the above using only the basic functions in Haskell (no library functions), and only using recursion.

However, I cannot seem to achieve a piece of code that works appropriately. This is the code that I have so far:

```
join :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
join [[a]] = [[a]]
join (n:ns:nss) | null nss == False = ((i n ns) : k (ns:nss))
                | otherwise = []
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: it might be easier to divide the problem into smaller pieces. for example start with a function that extracts just the first element from each sub-list `[[a]] -> ([[a]], [a])`. from there you could think of something like rotating the extracted list, then re-joining the elements to the end of each corresponding sub-list.

Comment: I would advise against using the name `join` as that's the name of an important function that's available in Prelude.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If only it were actually in Prelude

Comment: @amalloy - oops, so you're right, it's not. I could have sworn it was :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with higher-order functions, working in the *whole data*-manipulation paradigm:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import Data.List (unfoldr)
import Control.Arrow ( (>>>) )

rotateds :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
rotateds =
  map (splitAt 1)                     -- 1., 2.,
  >>> concatMap (\(a,b) -> [a,b])     -- 3.,
  >>> liftA2 (++) (drop 1) (take 1)   -- 4.,
  >>> unfoldr (Just . splitAt 2)      -- 5., 
  >>> takeWhile (not . null)          -- 5.,
  >>> map (\[a,b] -> (++) a b)        -- 6.
```

It passes all your tests. So yes it is possible. How it works is:

```
1. turn each sublist in the input  [    [a,b,c,...]  ,  [d,......]  , ... ]
2. into a pair                     [ ([a],[b,c,...]) , ([d], [...]) , ... ]
3. splice'em in                    [  [a],[b,c,...]  ,  [d], [...]  , ... ]
4. move the first letter over      [      [b,c,...]  ,  [d], ........ [a] ]
5. and restore the structure back to how it was 
    by reconstituting the pairs    [     [[b,c,...]  ,  [d]], ........... ]
6. and appending them together     [     [ b,c,...   ,   d ], ........... ]
```

Converting it to straight manual recursion <s>is a torturous task</s> is left as an exercise for an avid learner.

Comment: tuned out [not so torturous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70158282/849891) after all (but still using some `take`, `drop`, and `++).