# Moving the first element of a string to the last element of the preceding string using haskell

Tags: haskell

Been trying to figure this out for a couple days. For example:

```
k ["abc","def","ghi"] = ["bcd","efg","hia"]
k ["once","upon","a","time"] = ["nceu","pona","t","imeo"]
```

I'm trying to make one function using recursion and one without doing so. This is the closest I've gotten :\

```
k [] = []
k [[]] =[[]]
k [_:_] = [_:_]
k (x:xs:xss) = ([i x xs]  ++ [i xs (last (x:xs:xss))]  ++ [i (last (x:xs:xss)) x ]) : k [x]
```

```
> k ["once","upon","a","time"]
[["nceu","pont","imeo"]]
```

Any tips appreciated :)

edit: forgot to include a function made earlier

```
i :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
i [] y = y
i x [] = x
i x y = tail x ++ [head y]
```

Comment: Can you write a simpler function that rotates a single element around, `rotate :: [a] -> [a]`, with examples like `rotate "abcd" = "bcda"` and `rotate "once upon a time" = "nce upon a timeo"`? There are various ways to use that as a component to make the task at hand easier. You might also want to think about what you want `k ["abc", "", "def"]` to produce before sitting down to write code -- should it be `["bcd", "", "efa"]`, or `["bc", "d", "efa"]`, or what?

Comment: same problem is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100850/how-to-rotate-letters-in-a-list-of-strings-while-preserving-the-strings-shapes).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate letters in a list of strings while preserving the strings' shapes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70100850/how-to-rotate-letters-in-a-list-of-strings-while-preserving-the-strings-shapes)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

```
-- k [ "once","upon","a","time"] =
--   [  "nceu","pona","t","imeo"] 

k [] = []
k (x:xs)   =  g (take … x) (drop 1 … : xs)
g o (x:y:xs) =  (x ++ take 1 …) : g … (drop 1 y : xs)
g o [y]   =  [… ++ o]
g _ []   =  []  -- never used; keep compiler happy
```

You will need to complete this code.

If you're not familiar with `++`, `take` and / or `drop`, you'll have to implement them yourself. You can work out the requirements and hence implementations from their use in this code.

In particular, `drop 1 x =~= tail x` and `take 1 x =~= [head x]`, but better (won't cause errors for empty input).